# One Hot Encoding in Pytorch for two classes

Tags: python, pytorch, one-hot-encoding

I have a tensor of 0 and 1, which I calculated as follows:

```
for i in range(0,len(capital)):
if capital[i] <= 0:
    y.append(0)
else:
    y.append(1)
capital_t =  torch.Tensor(y)
```

I want to do a classification so, the zeros and ones in tensor capital_t have to be two classes. To do the same, I am trying to do one-hot encoding:

```
one_hot_capital = F.one_hot(capital_t,2)
```

I keep getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: one_hot is only applicable to index tensor.

Could anyone please help me debug this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message isn't clear, by "index tensor" it means a tensor of data type [`Tensor.long`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.long.html?highlight=long):

```
>>> F.one_hot(capital_t.long(), 2)
```

This will result in a tensor of shape `(*capital_t.shape, n_classes)`, which here corresponds to `(len(capital), 2)`.